# How to create a layout in Next JS 13 for admin dashboard sidebar?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, frontend

I am trying to create a layout for my dashboard. The dashboard has a sidebar that has links to different pages. But when I visit the dashboard page, my index.tsx is being displayed without the layout and sidebar.

I have attached a screenshot of my pages directory and the code for the layout file.

[image]

I have followed the documentation and tutorials, but almost everything that I've done is the same. The only major difference I see is - my layout is for the dashboard page (pages/dashboard) and not at the app level itself (pages). I also tried renaming the index.tsx to page.tsx, but that gives me a 404 page not found error.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename convention to use `layout`, `loader`, etc. is available only when you are using `app` directory. It is not available for `page` router.

To use layout with page router, you need to add it either to _app.tsx or the `index.tsx` file itself.

```
return <Layout>...</Layout>
```